# "Skip" in review isn't working

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

I tried to Skip, but nothing other than this happens:

[image]

It just sits there, hanging. I can now only Skip by removing the review id in the address bar (re-enter the queue). This is happening both in "Late Answers" and in "Triage".

I'm on Windows 10 / Opera.

Note: I didn't try any of the other buttons.. yet.

---

Update: Working again.

---

Update: And.. now the bug is back.

There are some more issues:

1. Pressing "flag" from inside the review doesn't bring up the pop-up.
2. It's not possible to upvote or downvote the post.
3. Upvoting a comment will shift the color to orange, but there's no increase to the count. And looking at the post in a different tab doesn't show the change of colour.
4. Commenting doesn't result in a comment on the post, but this seems to be the only way to make the "I'm done" button clickable. However, it has the same issue as "Skip".

I did not try to edit a post.

Comment: Just press the review tab above the skip button, that'll load a new review

Comment: Comment/answer about "AspNetCore canary servers" in 3...2...1...

Comment: @Nick Thank you. I still think it needs to be fixed, though :)

Comment: Oh no! It's getting worse!

Comment: The seems like it could be Internet connection issues - the network traffic your browser is sending back to the server (in response to your actions) is not getting there.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Wouldn't that be a very selective internet connection issue given I could post and edit this question multiple times during the entire time?

Comment: I dunno, but you get that sort of behavior if network packets are lost (could be in either direction).  Maybe something in between (firewall?) is dropping certain types of packets/traffiic?